# If statement doesnt work? Javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have two textboxes and one button. I putt numbers in the first textbox and press the button to add the number to a total which is displayed in the second box, till it reaches 1000. But the if statement doesn't work for some reason.

This works fine:

```
<html>
<title>Ask7</title>
<script>
var total=0;

function calculate()
{

    var box1;
    box1=parseFloat(document.getElementById("box1").value);
    total=total+box1;
    document.getElementById("box2").innerHTML="";
    document.getElementById("box2").value=total;


}
</script>
<body>

<h3>Give num:</h3>
<input id="box1" type="text"></input>
<button onclick="calculate()" type="button">ADD</button>
<br>

<h3>Total:</h3>
<input id="box2" readonly="readonly" type="text"></input>
</body>
</html>
```

This doesn't:

```
<html>
<title>Ask7</title>
<script>
var total=0;

function calculate()
{

if(total<1000)
{
    var box1;
    box1=parseFloat(document.getElementById("box1").value);
    total=total+box1;
    document.getElementById("box2").innerHTML="";
    document.getElementById("box2").value=total;
}
else
{
    alert("OVER 1000!");
    break;
}

}
</script>
<body>

<h3>Give num:</h3>
<input id="box1" type="text"></input>
<button onclick="calculate()" type="button">ADD</button>
<br>

<h3>Total:</h3>
<input id="box2" readonly="readonly" type="text"></input>
</body>
</html>
```

Basically I don't get why the if statement doesn't work.

Comment: `SyntaxError: unlabeled break must be inside loop or switch` ... [Learn how to **debug** JavaScript](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners)

Comment: It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/9ffDg/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `break`, it doesn't belong there.

I think you should have your code like this:

```
var total = 0;

function calculate() {
    var box1;
    box1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("box1").value);
    total = total + box1;
    box2 = document.getElementById("box2");
    box2.value = total;

    if (total < 1000) {
    // do something
    } else {
        alert("OVER 1000!");
        // break;
        box2.value = 0; // to clean the value after 1000
    }
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/TtsSG/)

Comment: Still it doesnt get in the if statement.

Comment: Good catch, although I don't think this causes the problem because javascript will stop there, however the code before should be executed.

Comment: @user2874565: Don't edit your original question like this. Now it appears that the answer doesn't make sense since there is no `break` in your code. But that was the problem.

Comment: i removed the break on my code and run it in chrome but it displays the first time i press add but not if i press again...wth.

Comment: @user2874565, check my updated answer with demo, is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @user2874565: Maybe you did something else wrong. As demonstrated, the code without `break` works in so far as that it executes the `if` and `else` branches. Of course if you meant something different by "the if statement doesn't work" then you should explain it. We don't know *how* you want it to "work".

Comment: Your code keeps adding to the total after it reaches 1000, I don't think that's wanted.

Comment: @Barmar, maybe. OP wrote "press the button to add the number to a total which is displayed in the second box"... we wait for OP to check my answer and reply to that question also.

Comment: @user2874565, please check this answer if its useful and what you want and check also @ Barmar's comment.

Comment: He also wrote "till it reaches 1000".

Comment: @Barmar, true. I just added a comment and included yours. (added also that possibility in my answer

Comment: @Sergio Ok thx a lot it seems i also had var total in the function as well originally and created some problems.

Comment: @user2874565, I see you joined Stackoverflow today, welcome! Check Felix King's comment about debugging. It might help you a next time.

Answer (score 0):

```
...
 else {
        alert("OVER 1000!");

        box2.value = 0; // to clean the value after 1000

        total = 0; // **** also reset the global var for reuse as still adding over 1000

}
```

Comment: In general, it's best to pull the explanation out and state in "regular speech" terms. Comments tend to hint at the idea, but rarely tell the full story.

Comment: i wanted to put as a comment in previous ans but i don't how, it wrking now :)